# Anything similar to wait_on_page_bit

Tags: linux-kernel

can anybody please tell me if there is any API or some other way i can use

```
 void wait_on_page_bit(struct page *page, int bit_nr)
```

As of now the wait_on_page_bit()  expects the nr_bit to be set and makes the thread sleep, it wakes up the thread when the bit i.e bit_nr is cleared.

In my case the bit it PG_Uptodate bit. It is cleared by default and i need to sleep my 
thread tell it is set, and thread should wake up.

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that `PG_Uptodate` is set within the locked page you can do the following:

```
do {
    wait_on_page_locked(page);
} while (PageUptodate(page);
```

Comment: thanks. but in my case PG_Uptodate is unset, so assumption is not true. Anyways i used wait_event_interrupt() and wake_up to do it.